# How do I embed Superset in an iframe?

Tags: apache-superset

I'm trying to embed Superset (version 1.3) in an iframe and I'm getting a DOMException 18. The installation of Superset itself works fine since I can access it normally at its URL. Ultimately, my need is to allow website X of a completely different origin to embed a view of my superset instance.

I've found a number of github issues and articles online suggesting changes to superset_config.py to allow embedding superset in an iframe and I've made a few of them. In particular, I've made the following changes to config.py (rather than superset_config.py as a temporary measure to be sure that the config changes were indeed being registered):

```
from .mysecurity import CustomSecurityManager
CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER = CustomSecurityManager
ENABLE_PROXY_FIX = True
HTTP_HEADERS: Dict[str, Any] = {'X-Frame-Options': 'ALLOWALL'}
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "None"
```

I'm using a [this](https://github.com/sairamkrish/superset-custom-authentication/blob/acf782a06f0abcd3cec8c903c1afd9d08244a9e0/config/security.py) as a base for custom security manager (the only changes are that I'm checking a token against another service before logging in the user and I'm providing a redirect in the URL).

This instance of superset is behind NGINX which is setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin *` and running with gunicorn.

The following screenshots are from my local host with a basic website that has the following bit of relevant JS logging in a user with role Gamma:

```
let analytics_div = document.getElementById('analytics');
let report = document.createElement("iframe")
const report_url = new URL("/superset/dashboard/123/?standalone=true", superset_url);
const start_url = new URL(`/login?auth_code=${superset_auth_token}&redirect=${report_url}`, superset_url)
report.src = start_url;
report.width = "100%"
report.height = 700
analytics_div.appendChild(report)
```

[Error I'm getting in the iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWctF.png)

[What I see in the dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdiYs.png)